# Fill a python dictionary with values from a pandas dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

This is my dictionary, called "reviews":

```
reviews= {1: {'like', 'the', 'acting'},
          2: {'hate', 'plot', 'story'}}
```

And this is my "lexicon" dataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

lexicon = {'word': ['like', 'movie', 'hate'],
    'neg': [0.0005, 0.0014, 0.0029],        
    'pos': [0.0025, 0.0019, 0.0002]
    }

lexicon = pd.DataFrame(lexicon, columns = ['word', 'neg','pos'])

print (lexicon)
```

[image: lexicon]

I need to fill my "reviews" dictionary with the neg and pos values from the "lexicon" dataFrame.

If there is no value in the lexicon, then I want to put 0.5

To finally get this outcome:

```
reviews= {1: {'like': [0.0005, 0.0025], 'the': [0.5, 0.5], 'acting': [0.5, 0.5]},
          2: {'plot': [0.5, 0.5], 'hate': [0.0029, 0.0002], 'story': [0.5, 0.5]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) here.

```
df_ = lexicon.set_index("word").agg(list, axis=1)
out = {k: df_.reindex(v, fill_value=[0.5, 0.5]).to_dict() for k, v in reviews.items()}

# {1: {'the': [0.5, 0.5], 'like': [0.0005, 0.0025], 'acting': [0.5, 0.5]},
# 2: {'story': [0.5, 0.5], 'hate': [0.0029, 0.0002], 'plot': [0.5, 0.5]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create dictionary from `lexicon` and then in double dictionary comprehension mapping by `dict.get` for possible add default value if no match:

```
d = lexicon.set_index('word').agg(list, axis=1).to_dict()
print (d)
{'like': [0.0005, 0.0025], 'movie': [0.0014, 0.0019], 'hate': [0.0029, 0.0002]}


out = {k: {x: d.get(x, [0.5,0.5]) for x in v} for k, v in reviews.items()}
print (out)
{1: {'like': [0.0005, 0.0025], 'the': [0.5, 0.5], 'acting': [0.5, 0.5]}, 
 2: {'story': [0.5, 0.5], 'hate': [0.0029, 0.0002], 'plot': [0.5, 0.5]}}
```